# Apply a date filter on simple CSV file and make result as a new CSV file

Tags: javascript, php, html, csv

I'm totally newbie with PHP and Javascript,

i have a very simple CSV file called "data.csv" that holds 3 datas on each line : epoch time in ms , temperature value , humidity value.

Each line terminated with \r\n characters.

ie :

```html
1485320400000,22.5,30\r\n
1485342000000,23.8,32\r\n
1485360000000,24.5,29\r\n
1485363600000,21.0,30.5\r\n
1485410400000,25.5,34.5\r\n
1485439200000,23.0,28.5\r\n
```

I would like to let a user from a simple web page with textboxes to enter a start date and end date in order to keep datas only within this datetime windows and build a new CSV file with a different name filled-in only with these values.

[JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lcoulon/aj22m9h9/)

I was thinking about a PHP code that would GET the user entry from an HTML page, convert starting and ending dates as epoch time (in ms) then remove all lines in the CSV file before and after specified dates in order to build a new CSV file afterwards named data_filtered.csv

Can you show me how to do that please ?

Comment: Sir, you need to provide some code that you were "thinking" about. People here can help sort the problems in code.

Comment: The complete answer to your question would be a tutorial and I'm afraid StackOverflow is not the right place for that. You're thinking right with PHP code GETting date from HTML and filtering the lines from CSV file. Start doing it. When you hit some more definite problem (e.g. how to create in PHP a new CSV file with only the desired lines) the people here will be happy to help you.